# event handles & visible

Tags: c#, .net

Ok I am working on a project for my class. I have to make everything on one page, have a menu on the top. In the menu it is suppose to have new,open,From Html,save,and exit. I have all but the From HTML one done. I am kinda confused. with everything needed to be on one page when the user click the From HTML it show show a textbox and a button then you should be able to put in a web address and click go and the html code shows up in the richtextbox. Now the problem I am having is getting it all to word right. This is what I have so far..

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         WebRequest myRequest;
        myRequest = WebRequest.Create("//");
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string line="";
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.Append(line);
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();

    }
```

as you can see this line has this

```
 myRequest = WebRequest.Create("//");
```

being the fact I kind forget how to have it set to blank for the user to enter in there information. Or is there a way that when they click on From HTML that a messagebox can come up with the textbox and button but displays in the richTextBox?
I forgot to add this code

```
private void fromHTMLToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

This is where the messagebox should be a something with visible when the user click this button so it shows the textbox and button to display the HTML in the richtext area.

EDIT: I have a panel group which is called panel1. It has the button and the textbox for the user to enter in the URL that they want to. Know my question is when the peron clicks on From HTML I need to get the panel visible for only that one. So would I click on the panel and how would I only have it visible for only that one.

Comment: is this winforms, WPF, or ASP.NET?  Please update your tags to clarify.  And "files and streams" is an incredibly undescriptive title - consider editing that too.

Comment: Well this is what I am working on and that is what it is called.

Comment: @Jason has a point, though -- if you're looking for people to help you answer the question, a clearer title might make it easier for them.  "Files and streams" can mean a lot of things, in different languages, to different people, not all of whom have the expertise you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to give you the full answer, but here's a place to start:

`MessageBox` presents the user with a message and lets him click a button in response, but you can't add controls to it.  Instead, you'll have to define another form that contains your textbox and confirmation button, and open it in the handler for `fromHTMLToolStripMenuItem_Click`.  You could set a property in that form to hold the user's response (the desired URI), and retrieve it in the event handler when the form returns.

Comment: Ok i am trying to understand you are saying define another form that contains your textBox and confirmation button.Am I right? But the thing is I have to have it all on the same page. Now is there a way to make it visible only when the user click the From HTML?

Comment: Aha, okay.  Winforms `Control`s have a `Visible` property and an `Enabled` property.  Check those out.

Comment: I think you might be missing my point.  WinForms is an API for producing Windows applications, which are programmed in a .net language like C#.  You can also use the .net framework and C# to program an ASP.net web application, or a console application that opens in what looks like a DOS box.

Presuming you are doing a Windows app, you're probably using Winforms (and the signature of the `ToolStripMenuItem` handler would suggest that), you should be able to use the Visible property of a control to display or hide it.

Comment: Yes,sorry misunderstood. I did figure that part out now I am just trying to figure out how to do the other part I was needing help on with the myRequest = WebRequest.Create("//"); and have it where the user can input the url and click the go button and it will go to that.

Comment: MSDN (Microsoft Developer Network) has the full documentation on any method or object you're curious about.  In this case, [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) explains you'd pass in a URI to the `WebRequest.Create` call in place of "//".  The URI you pass in should come from whatever control the user types it into.