# WebRequest enter URL

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [event handles & visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180156/event-handles-visible)

I am new to learning WebRequest.This is my code

```
        WebRequest myRequest;
        myRequest = WebRequest.Create("");
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string line = "";
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.Append(line);
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

I am having trouble understanding how to allow the user to enter the URL and click the button and that page shows up.Can some help me understand . Where it says
myRquest = WebRequest.Create(""); when the user enters the URL in the textbox and clicks the go button that it will go to that web page.

Comment: You just asked this question and accepted an answer.  Why are you asking again?

Comment: I had two questions in there and I know the one time I got in trouble for having the other one answer on the same form. I got told to ask it in a new question. There was two parts to the one question I figure the one out and I am still not understanding the WebRequest.

Comment: Vote to close. You sample code, title and question say 3 different things. You may get better response if you align at least 2 of them. Note that your previous question contains directions to the answer - "enter text" is second most basic sample for WinForms application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you have a TextBox on your page (txtUrl) that the user uses to type in the Url.  Then you would do something like this

```
  myRequest = WebRequest.Create(txtUrl.Text);
```

That passes the url the user entered into the WebRequest.Create() method.  However, you'll need to add some error checking in case the user does not enter a value, or enters a bad url, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Just the simple things that you kinda forget.